Wrong greeks (delta, vega, ...) results when requesting data using reqMktData
I am using the native library ibapi (Interactive Brokers). I have the following code:
    from ibapi.client import EClient
    from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
    from ibapi.contract import Contract
    import threading
    import time

    class TradingApp(EWrapper, EClient):
        def __init__(self):
            EClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)
            self.nextOrderId = None
            self.option_params_received = False

        def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString, advancedOrderRejectJson=None):
            print("Error {} {} {}".format(reqId, errorCode, errorString))

        def tickOptionComputation(self, reqId, tickType, impliedVol, delta, optPrice, pvDividend, gamma, vega, theta, undPrice, pvDividend2):
        
            if tickType == 13:  # This is the type for option computation
                print(f"Greeks for reqId {reqId}: Delta={delta}, Gamma={gamma}, Vega={vega}, Theta={theta}")

    def websocket_con():
        app.run()

    # Create an instance of the TradingApp class and connect to the server.
    app = TradingApp()
    print("Attempting to connect...")
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=7)

    # Create a thread to connect to the websocket.
    con_thread = threading.Thread(target=websocket_con)
    con_thread.start()

    # Give some lag time for connection
    time.sleep(2)

    # Create a simple put options contract on AAPL
    option_contract = Contract()
    option_contract.symbol = "AAPL"  # Added symbol for the underlying
    option_contract.secType = "OPT"
    option_contract.currency = "USD"
    option_contract.exchange = "SMART"
    option_contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "20240802"
    option_contract.strike = 195
    option_contract.tradingClass = 'AAPL'
    option_contract.right = "P"  # Put option

    app.reqMktData(reqId=111, 
               contract=option_contract, 
               genericTickList= "101",
               snapshot=False, 
               regulatorySnapshot=False,
               mktDataOptions=[])

    time.sleep(5)

    app.cancelMktData(111)

The problem I have is that the results for all greeks are wrong from what I see in the TWS. I am using real-time data, no snapshots. I see the values in parallel (no timing issue), and the options contract is described in detail. The result for the delta is even a positive value, although I sent a request for a put option. Is there anything I forgot in the code to receive the same values I see in TWS?

Meanwhile I found the answer.
Reviewing the code, you can see that the tickOptionComputation function was incorrectly defined. The parameters are not ordered appropriately.
Incorrect function definition:
def tickOptionComputation(self, reqId, tickType, impliedVol, delta, optPrice, pvDividend, gamma, vega, theta, undPrice, pvDividend2)

Correct function definition:
def tickOptionComputation(self, reqId, tickType, tickAttrib, impliedVol, delta, optPrice, pvDividend, gamma, vega, theta, undPrice)

